# hash / pound / number '#' sign as library method name in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to call a method of a DLL which name starts with '#' char, i.e.

```
from ctypes import cdll
lib_h = cdll.LoadLibrary("myDLL.dll")
```

Now, how can I possibly call the method called '#7'? For example

```
fun = lib_h.#7
```

interprets the # as the start of a comment.

Comment: You might be able to use `getattr(lib_h, '#7')`, but accessing attributes whose names aren't valid identifiers is always going to be tricky (see also names that conflict with keywords).

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What was the language (that allows func names to start with a `#`) used to create the dll?